# the child has also got selected while pressing parent in listview?

Tags: android, listview, background, android-listview, state

[image]

when i press the list ,the imageview has also got selected ..

For Imageview

```
         <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:state_pressed="true"   
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_light" />
           <
             <item
     android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
      </selector>
```